# I can't close softinput under certain condition

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-dialog

If I add the deley, it works.What's the reason?

```
 final AlertDialog dialog0 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("0")
                .setView(view)
                .show();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final AlertDialog dialog1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(TestActvt.this).setTitle("1").setMessage("222").show();

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        dialog1.dismiss();
                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
//                                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
//                                    @Override
//                                    public void run() {
                                        dialog0.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
                                        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
                                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                                        view.requestFocus();
                                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
//                                    }
//                                },1000);
                            }
                        },100);

                    }
                },3000);
            }
        },3000);
```

Comment: View view = this.getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
        }

Comment: A-n-v-e-s-h don't post answer as a comment please.

Comment: tiny sunlight can you post your code please?

Comment: I add my code , you can have a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
```